# problem in writing equation with one bigg bracket

Tags: equations

I am writing the code for this equation

[image]

I tried this code

```
\begin{equation}  
\left\{  \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  if {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \right\}
\left\{  \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  if {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau \right\}
\end{equation}
```

I am unable to shift the second line `\hat{y}_{i}^{k} = 1 if {S}_{i}^{k} > \tau` to the next line by using big curly bracket, and I want to put a bracket on both sides.

How to also add space between each symbol?

Comment: Use the `cases` environment.

Comment: but it only puts bracket at right side .. how to put bracket at left side

Comment: What do you mean by right side? The bracket is in the left side.

Comment: @user12 - The screeenshot you show doesn't have a bracket on the right. If that's something you want, you should say so somewhere explicitly.

Comment: see the question first i wrote in question ..then give suggestion thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four usual ways to the problem of which anyone could be choosed as you like and are used very often. Of course, some unusual packages may also supply different ways which is not advised by me since they may be more complicated and used quite few.

1. By the normal `cases` environment in the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{cases}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. By the `\left\{ \right.` codes and the `array` environment in the `amsmath` package. And you could add 1 to 3 `\!` to adjust the space after the left brace or before the right brace.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \left\{    
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{array}
    \right.
    \end{equation}
    
       \begin{equation}
    \left.   
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{array}
    \right\}
    \end{equation}
    
       \begin{equation}
    \left\{    
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{array}
    \right\}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

3. By the `\left\{ \right.` codes and the `aligned` environment in the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    &\hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
    &\hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
    &\hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
    &\hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    &\hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
    &\hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

4. By the `dcases` or `dcases*` environment in the `mathtools` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{dcases}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{dcases}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{dcases*}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  &if  ${S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau$ \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  &if ${S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau$
    \end{dcases*}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{rcases}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{rcases}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{rcases*}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  &if  ${S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau$ \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  &if ${S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau$
    \end{rcases*}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need the `cases` environment as I commented.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{cases}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Edit: To put a bracket also on the right side, you may use the `\Biggr\}` (courtesy of @barbarabeeton) command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 0  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  <  \tau \\
        \hat{y}_{i}^{k}  = 1  & \text{if } {S}_{i}^{k}  >  \tau
    \end{cases}\Biggr\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\Biggr\} might yield more symmetrical spacing.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear. If you want a solution that mimics the screenshot you posted, use a `cases` environment, as is used, say, in [@Imran's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641165/5001).

If, in contrast, you want to enclose a two-row expression in tall curly braces, I suggest you  encase either a two-column `array` environment or a `Bmatrix*[l]` environment.

Both possibilities are illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'matrix*[l]' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}  
\begin{cases}
\hat{\mathcal{Y}}_{k}^{i} = 0 & \text{if ${\mathcal{S}}_{k}^{i} < \tau$,} \\
\hat{\mathcal{Y}}_{k}^{i} = 1 & \text{if ${\mathcal{S}}_{k}^{i} > \tau$.} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}  
\begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
\hat{\mathcal{Y}}_{k}^{i} = 0 & \text{if ${\mathcal{S}}_{k}^{i} < \tau$} \\[0.75ex]
\hat{\mathcal{Y}}_{k}^{i} = 1 & \text{if ${\mathcal{S}}_{k}^{i} > \tau$} 
\end{Bmatrix*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `alignedat` and the `empheq` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{empheq}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace, right=\empheqrbrace]{equation}        \begin{alignedat}{2}
    \hat{y}_{i}^{k} & = 0 &\quad & \text{ if } S_{i}^{k} < \tau \\
    \hat{y}_{i}^{k} &= 1 & & \text{ if }S_{i}^{k} > \tau
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{empheq}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for warning me, Milady! I confess I often forget to check what I post.